# Asp.Net CSS Friendly Menu Adapter

Tags: asp.net

I have used the CSS Friendly menu in one of my projects and have found it great, however I have 2 different areas in the same project and would like to use the CSS Friendly menu in just some of my pages.

How can I prevent all other menus from using the Css Friendly menu dll?

Thank you

Josimari

Answer (score 1):

There's a propery that the CSS Friendly adapters look for called "AdapterEnabled". If you add this to each control you don't want to use the CSS Friendly adapters and set it to "false" then they should render using the standard framework method.

Comment: Hi Brian, it ALMOST solved it. Now it has been rendered as a default asp.net menu but without applying the styles I have choosen for it. It just renders correctly when I remove the CSSFriendlyAdapter.Browser from the App_Browser dir, but then, the css menu stop working. Any Idea?